# Counterexample in Kolmogorov theorem about existence of almost surely continuous modification

Tags: stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, expected-value

I want to understand this Kolmogorov theorem about existence of almost surely continuous modification:

  A process $\{\xi_t, \in[0,T]\}$ admits an almost surely continuous modification if there exist constants $a,b,c>0$ such that $$\mathbb{E}[|\xi_t-\xi_s|^a]\leq b|t-s|^{1+c}$$ for all $s,t\in [0,T]$. 

 
And I have such a question. What if we take a process $\{\xi_t=e^{w_t^3}, t\in[0,T]\}$, where $w_t$ is  standard wiener process. Then will it be determined $\mathbb{E}[|\xi_t-\xi_s|^a]$ ?

Comment: You are right, this will not be integrable. However, the Kolmogorov theorem it also true with $|\cdot|^a$ replaced by $\max\{|\cdot|^a,1\}$.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @zhoraster The problem is that I still can't understand why we conclude about non-integrability. Why is it true  $\forall a$?

Comment: The function $e^{a |x|^3 - b x^2}$ is non-integrable for any $a>0$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @zhoraster Sorry, but how did we move from this $e^{w_t^3}$ to this $e^{a|x|^3−bx^2}$ ?

Comment: The absolute value is in fact irrelevant. Just write the expectation in question as the integral of the function times the density.